# how to retrieve mails from gmail using imap and oauth 2 in php?

Tags: php, email, oauth-2.0, gmail, imap

I want to read mails from gmail using IMAP and oauth 2, Currently i followed code but it is based on user password, I want oauth 2 refresh token instead of it. Is their is any other way to acheive it,Please help me.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app

Comment: This is a FULL implementation of standard PHP IMAP functions like (imap_open, imap_getmailboxes, imap_*, etc...) https://github.com/ddeboer/imap/issues/443#issuecomment-1172158902 @laurel